# Telerik Rad Editor - jquery attribute gets appended to <a> tag during the save (only in IE 8)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am coming across one very unsual problem in Rad Editor under IE 8 browser. When i save the webpage, if i have any  tags in my editor. It gets converted into something like this:-

```
<A href="http://www.yahoo.com" jQuery1327463946887="77" jQuery1327464032854="14">yahoo</A><BR>
```

Every time i save the content, the jquery attribute gets appended to the achor tag. Thus the content becomes very large, although these attributes are giving no problem but it is increasing the html content unnecessary. And this thing is happening only in IE. I am using jQuery Library in my proj.

Does anyone else also having this kind of problem ? Pls share the information..

I found the cause. Inside the telerik rad control markup, there is an event known as OnClientModeChange. And in my case, i am calling this js method.

```
  function stopLinks(editor) {        
        var links = editor.get_document().getElementsByTagName("a");
        links = j$(links);        
        links.click(function () { return false; });
    }
```

The above code is doing havoc in IE, especially when the click event is binded to return false. It is appending jQuery1327463946887="77". Can someone suggest the better alternative to the above jquery fn. Rad editor has some problem with the use of this jquery code in IE.

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the ability to click on an anchor element, wouldn't it be better to just strip out all `<a></a>` tags and only leave the text for the URL? You should be able to do that with a regular expression. In fact, this post's answer has a sample function you can use which would just leave you with the text between the `<a></a>` tags.